# Visual Studio's "Go To All" feature: Any way to customize the order of the results?

Tags: visual-studio

I use Go To All a lot for navigation. But I find the order of the results isn't very good/useful. For example, in this search for STD, which I wanted to find SceneTransitionDirector, I get a lot of other stuff first:

[image]

Is there any control over customizing the way Go To All displays results? I almost always want all-caps to first find pascalcase matches for what I've typed, then ideally whole words, and only substring/partial matches last. Do we have any control over this?

I'm using VS 2019, but I can also upgrade to a newer version if the feature exists. Thanks.

Comment: Visual Studio is not a good way to catch STDs